# assign a double value from the model to a property of a control

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a very struggling problem:

In the Model, I have this property:

```
Double ConversionRate;
```

I would like to assign that value to a property of a control:

```
<StoreControl:StoreUI ConversionRate="10.1">
```

It works when I try to hard-coded the value but when I try it like this:

```
<StoreControl:StoreUI ID="StoreUI1" runat="server" ConversionRate='<% (double)Model.ConversionRate %>'>
```

Then I got this error:

```
Cannot create an object of type 'System.Double' from its string representation
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: ASP.NET MVC doesn't use controls.

Comment: really? so how can I reuse controls from Asp.NET?

Comment: Have you tried removing `(double)`?

Comment: Yes, I did too but there is still an error

Comment: Same error? Where does the error occur? What is returned by `Model.ConversionRate` when the error occurs?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
'<%: (double)Model.ConversionRate %>'
```

Or Alternately

```
'<%= (double)Model.ConversionRate %>'
```

Hope this will help !!

Comment: These two solutions don't help. It shows 0??? but the true value is not 0. What is wrong?

Comment: What value you have assigned to it in your controller?